# Visa to Japan for a Kazakstan citizens living in Shanghai

Tags: visas, japan

I am from Kazakhstan living in Shanghai. I am planning to visit Japan this April, could you please share your experience getting a visa to Japan in Shanghai? Maybe the name of the travel agencies that I can contact ?

Comment: "Sharing experiences" is very open-ended and sounds more like an invitation to a discussion than a question: we're not a discussion site. Do you have a specific question you want to know the answer to? Recommending commercial companies isn't really on-topic here, either.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mofa.go.jp/announce/announce/2007/5/1173415_826.html) the [Shanghai consulate](http://www.shanghai.cn.emb-japan.go.jp/) would be the place to go if you'd be Chinese. It is reasonable to try there first and forget any travel agencies. They are much less likely to be able to deal with a non-Chinese citizen in this and even if they could, it's likely they will charge you for a service you don't need.